# Comparing Three Floats in a C Function

Tags: c, function, if-statement, max

I wrote this in C, to try and get a max value for get_extreme, but it's not returning a result in the compiler.

It's supposed to return the maximum float value, or if the maximum is all three, return that result.

```
int get_extreme(float num1, float num2, float num3) {

/* local variable declaration */
int result;

if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3 ){
    result = num1;
}
else if (num1 > num2 && num2 > num3){
    result = num1;}
else if (num2 > num3 && num3 > num1){
    result = num2;}
else {
    result = num3;}

return result;
}
```

Comment: If it's supposed to return a float, why is result defined as an `int`? And why does the function return an `int`?

Comment: So what is it returning for the inputs you've tried?

Comment: OK, so I fixed that, but now the results its returning are ridiculous.

Comment: That's because your algorithm is completely wrong. You only account for two possible permutations. There are 6 in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined result as an `int`. Also the return value. But when you assign a value to the result variable, you assign a float.

And your logics seems to be wrong. You return `num3` in case `num1` is greater than `num2` and `num3` is greater than `num2` and `num1` is grater than `num3` for example.
Change the conditions to:

```
if (num1>=num2&& num1>=num3) 
result=num1;
else if (num2>=num1&& num2>=num3) 
result=num2;
else
result=num3;
```

Comment: Still throwing weird numbers….

Comment: hmm can you write the whole function that produces the wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

```
float get_extreme(float num1, float num2, float num3) {

    /* local variable declaration */
    float result;

    if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) {
       result = num1;
    } else if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
       result = num1;
    } else if (num2 > num3 && num2 > num1) {
       result = num2;
    } else {
       result = num3;
    }

    return result;
 }
```

Comment: There aren't enough permutations. Apparently there's 6 possible comparisons to be made.

Comment: This function should definitely work fine. Did you try it?

Comment: you have one unnecessary condition. the first one. If they are all equal the last, would return just fine.